# disadvantage of using hibernate or another ORM in a Spring application

Tags: hibernate, orm, spring-data

What is the disadvantages of using Hibernate or other ORM into a spring application that handles a lot of data ( a single table in db can contain xxxxxx rows )

Comment: Please clarify whether you wish to know the disadvantages of ORM in general or specifically when used with Spring.  And, also qualify `lot of data` - what kind of application (web, reporting, etc.), how many tables, what kind of relationships, number of rows, etc., whether all or only a few use cases will access all the data.

Comment: I downvoted the question because it is not clear enough